# Concatenation of first letter alike regardless of upper and lower case in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, concatenation, case-insensitive

i have been figuring out how to combine strings that has first same letter alike regardless of their cases. I have a code that if you input

> babe,two,Bird,Tea

the output is always like this

> babe,Bird,Tea,two

But the input that I want to see is like this

> babeBird,Teatwo

What am i going to add or change in my code in order for me to do that. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
char str1[1000][1000], str[1000], temp[1000];
int n, i, p, j, a;
char *ptr, *ptr1, letter;


printf("Enter how many arrays: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("Enter string %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", &str1[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
    {
    if (tolower((unsigned char)str1[i][0]) == tolower((unsigned char)str1[j][0])
   ){
       strcpy(temp, str1[i]);
       strcpy(str1[i], str1[j]);
       strcpy(str1[j], temp);
    }
   if(strcasecmp(str1[i], str1[j])>0)
   {
       strcpy(temp, str1[i]);
       strcpy(str1[i], str1[j]);
       strcpy(str1[j], temp);
     }
   }
}

 for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
  if (i != 0)
    {
    else if (str1[i][0] != letter)
    {
        printf(",");
    }
  }


    {
printf("%s", str1[i]);
letter = str1[i][0];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using scanf to split the strings, which means you need to put a space after each comma (otherwise it will read everything as one word), and the ending comma is part of each string. You need to check for that comma and remove it.

Comment: *"the gods shall surely punish thee for thy arrogance..."* See [Henry Spencer's 10 Commandments for C Programmers -- No. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) *"Ye be warned..."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code which decides whether to print a comma

```
if (str1[i][0] != letter)
```

does a case-sensitive comparison.

Change it to something like

```
if (tolower(str1[i][0]) != tolower(letter))
```

However, the code contains multiple bugs (too many to point them all out), so not sure it will work. You might want to do debugging.